# How to order by value when i get results in array?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I get all tags and its look like this :

```
"testeng" => 0
"testeng1" => 5
```

So what i want to do is order this by value so that first one is this with value 5. Any suggestion how can i do this?

```
$tags = ATags::with('articles')->whereHas('language',function($query) use($current_language_id){
  $query->where('id','=',$current_language_id);
})->get();
$count_tag = [];
foreach($tags as $tag){
  $count_tag[$tag->name] = $tag->articles->count();
}
```

Comment: Can you let me know from where did you get this - `"testeng" => 0, "testeng1" => 5`...?

Comment: $count_tag[$tag->name] = $tag->articles->count();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Collection's [`sortBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortby) or [`sortByDesc`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortbydesc) & [`count`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count) methods to sort your results like this:

```
$tags = ATags::with('articles')->whereHas('language',function($query) use($current_language_id) {
  $query->where('id','=',$current_language_id);
})
->get()
->sortByDesc(function($tag) {  // <---- sorting it via article's count
    return $tag->articles->count();
})
->take(5); // <----- fetch largest 5 from collection
```

> You can pass a closure method to `sortBy` or `sortByDesc` collection's methods to manipulate your results.

Comment: Just one more question... where i can put limit so that i display only 5 records, so that i display only 5 records with biggest numbers?

Comment: You can put limit before the `get()` method like this - `->limit(5)->get()`. Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried that but when i do that ordering has change... i dont get on first place record with biggest number

Comment: @None - So in that case, you can just use `take()` method after the `sortByDesc()` method on collection like this - `get()->sortByDesc(...)->take(5)`

Comment: thats it.. tnx :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`arsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) as:

```
 arsort($count_tag)
```

> arsort — Sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association

OR

You can use [`withCount`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) to sort the result directly in query as:

```
$tags = ATags::with('articles')
                ->whereHas('language',function($query) use($current_language_id){
                  $query->where('id','=',$current_language_id);
                })
                ->withCount('articles')
                ->orderBy('articles_count', 'desc')
                ->take(5)
                ->get();
```

From the docs

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without
>   actually loading them you may use the `withCount` method, which will
>   place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

Comment: dont you think, it is better to use `ORM orderBy` instead of `arsort()`

Comment: how can i use this in my example?

Comment: Just do `arsort($count_tag)` after your `foreach` and your `$count_tag` will be updated.